# “Not a valid Win32 application” on XP but not Win 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, win32

I am getting a "Not a valid Win32 application" error message when attempting to execute an .EXE downloaded from Microsoft on Windows XP, but it executes fine on Windows 7.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Which application?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like it's probably a 64-bit app you're trying to run on a 32-bit machine.

Comment: Some win32 exe's coded for Windows 7 will not run in XP with the same error message, we need to know what they downloaded to know for sure.